# How to change the order of input method in Mac OS X Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, input-source

I'm using Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.5 (18F132) and i'm trying to change the order of the input method (different language), particularly I want to change the order of the 2nd and 3rd languages. Any idea on how I can do that?

Thanks a lot.
Arthur

Comment: Hey Arthur, welcome to Apple.SE! If there aren't a lot of them, What about deleting both and adding them in opposite order?

Comment: Hi @ankiiiiiii!
Thanks for responding. I tried deleting the languages in various order and then adding them back and they would always show up in the predefined new order.
I know it's not a major issue, it's just a matter of getting used to, but since I also work on windows, where I have the old order im used to, it would really help.
Cheers!